# Solving systems of linear equations non directly

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

Consider the system of linear equations

$$\mathbf A \mathbf x = \mathbf b,$$

where $\mathbf A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is invertible and $\mathbf b \in \mathbb R^n$. Let $\mathbf D \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be a diagonal and invertible.

We can solve the system $\mathbf A \mathbf x = \mathbf b$ directly. However, I want to show that if we solve it such a way that we calculate $\mathbf D \mathbf A \mathbf D$ and $\mathbf D\mathbf b$, solve the system $\mathbf D \mathbf A \mathbf D \mathbf y = \mathbf D\mathbf b$, and calculate $\mathbf x = \mathbf D \mathbf y$. Then this  $\mathbf x$ will be the same  $\mathbf x $ as solving it directly.

Using Algorithm GEPP (Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting), how would you go about showing that the vector $\mathbf x$ calculated in Approach 2 indeed solves $\mathbf A \mathbf x = \mathbf b$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since $D$ is invertible $DADy=Db \implies ADy=b$. Then $ADy=Ax$ and since $A$ is invertible...

Comment: I don't understand. Aren't you merely left-multiplying both sides by $\bf D$ and then re-scaling $\bf x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we solve your second equation, we get :

$$y=\left(DAD \right)^{-1}Db=D^{-1}A^{-1}D^{-1}Db=D^{-1}A^{-1}b $$

so you get :

$$Dy=A^{-1}b=x $$ by your first definition